# How to order a CakePHP query by an aggregate function on an associated table's field?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I want to order by an aggregate function on an associated table's field, but when I debug the SQL query being executed, the associated table, `PersonaHistory` doesn't even get `JOIN`ed, and of course I don't get any results.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Can I force a table to be joined in the query?

```
$query = $this->Personas->find('all')
    ->contain(['PersonaHistory'])
    ->order(['MAX(PersonaHistory.updated)' => 'ASC'])
    ->group('PersonaHistory.persona_id');
```

DB: `Personas has many PersonaHistory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if `Personas` is related to `PersonaHistory` via `hasMany`. Only `hasOne` and `belongsTo` associations produce a `JOIN` statement.

A workaround is to rewrite your query as:

```
$query = $this->PersonaHistory->find('all')
    ->contain(['Personas'])
    ->order(['MAX(PersonaHistory.updated)' => 'ASC'])
    ->group('PersonaHistory.persona_id');
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the query is much more complex, and if I'm gonna rebuild it, I prefer to just write the SQL query which I already did and tested and worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

your table name need to be plurialized and you can execute your order and group directly on your associated table field

```
<?php $query = $this->Personas->find('all')->contain([
    'PersonaHistories' => function ($q) {
        return $q->order(['Max(updated)' => 'ASC'])
                 ->group('persona_id');
    }]);
```

Comment: Changing the table name makes Cake behave differently?